# Removing NaN value by grouping based on column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have dataframe like this:

```
            Time  Voltage [V]  Current [A]  Temperature [C]
0  1659545144000       25.780          NaN              NaN
1  1659545144000          NaN        0.287              NaN
2  1659545144000          NaN          NaN             19.0
```

I want to groupby them by Time as in each time, step we have one V, A, and C. Eventually the final df looks like this:

```
            Time  Voltage [V]  Current [A]  Temperature [C]
0  1659545144000       25.780         0.287            19.0
```

Note that I posted sample three lines, I have 500,000 row in each dataset.

Comment: You can do : `df.groupby('Time').first()` assuming you have only one valid value in each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
print(df.groupby("Time", as_index=False).max())
```

Prints:

```
            Time  Voltage [V]  Current [A]  Temperature [C]
0  1659545144000        25.78        0.287             19.0
```

Comment: I didn't know we could compare numbers with NaN! Great solution, thanks!